# MongoDB Compass filter does not begin with

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB Compass as GUI for the database.

I'm trying to filter where title does not begin with p, I have this in the filter field - which is straight from the mongodb docs:

```
{ title: { $not: /^p.*/ } }
```

However, the 'Find' button is still disabled... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) and the "not starts with `p`" pattern

```
{ title: {"$regex": "^(?!p)"} }
```